# set focus on different textboxes as different div is visible on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a page where on page load event I've set focus on a textbox using javascript. But after button press I've to set focus on different text box of different asp:Panel. Is this possible using javascript? Currently I am doing this via code behind page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
        $(function () {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPassengerId.ClientID%>').focus();
        });
    </script>
<asp:Panel ID = "firstPanel" >
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassengerId" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn_search" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btn_search_Click" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID = "secondPanel" >
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDestination" runat="server"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

After the button pressed secondPanel is visible and I need to focus on txtDestination text box. Is this possible using javascript?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to use the selector you've used "document.getElementById" and use the .focus() function.

```
document.getElementById("secondpanel").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("txtDestination").focus();
```

should do it. if you need more just comment.

Comment: Sorry just realised that the selector for the .focus should have id txtDestination not secondpanel

Comment: It is not working. The condition is when the `secondpanel` is visible then only the focus should be on `txtDestination`.

Comment: @user4221591 I've edited the answer to correct the ID issue, if you want to make it so the initial text box can't have something entered into it after focusing onto the second one then you can just make the _.readOnly_ value true on the first one so even if they go back onto it they cannot edit it.